# Implementing a basic CNN using tensorflow in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a 2-class classification problem in hand. I have extracted a set of 3 features for each training example .. I am planning to use a very simple CNN to learn the weights. My model looks like[image]

I am planning to use tensorflow for implementing this CNN in python. The official tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/ seems to be somewhat abstract . Can I get a basic code to train this?

Comment: Are you trying to understand CNN by implementing this? If so, you can take any data set from data.world and use it to experiment.

Comment: I am infact trying to understand CNN and machine learning in general . I dont have a problem with dataset . From the accepted answer , I guess keras does the task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be missing the point of CNN, which require signal with **spatial relations** (such as raw images, audio, etc.). Convolving signal with **three** features  makes pretty much no sense (pretty much the only option would be a 2x1 filter convolving among the only axis, leading to nearly regular MLP). What you are looking for is rather basic classifier, and in general - neural nets are probably not the good choice (they are not good models for small, low-dimensional problems), you should be fine with models like kernelized SVM, and other classifiers which are available in scikit-learn. For basic TF code look at its [basic tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/beginners/), since as said before - this is not a problem for CNN. Furthermore, TF is not a simple library which trains a model in few lines of code, if you are looking for this kind of things you should rather take a look at keras, tf-slim or other libraries built on top of TF.

Comment: Thank you . That pretty much summarizes what I am looking for